# Copy prototype functions from object in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
case "CONNECTOR_CONNECTION_FULFILLED":
    state = {
        ...state,
        appState: 'loggedIn'
    };
    state.ourPlayer = { ...action.payload.player }

    break;
```

So when my app fires this action, it creates a player object for my app to use. The player object has prototype methods (player.spawn(), player.killed(), etc) on it though and when I copy it this way those don't get copied.

Comment: The Redux docs [strongly recommend against](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state) putting non-serializable items (like functions) in your store. If your Redux reducers modify player state, then you should make them plain objects and use reducers instead of instance methods like `killed`. If your reducers don't modify the player state, then you should just do `state.ourPlayer = action.payload.player`,

Answer (score 1):

The `{ ...someObject }` object spread syntax, as well as the `Object.assign` method copies only the object's own enumerable properties. Non enumerable props, the prototype props, and the prototype itself are not copied.

So, while, *that's not a recommended practice in the redux world*, you can create some kind of a *copy constructor* for your domain objects, for example:

```
class Player {
  constructor(anotherPlayer) {
    // copy the props of another player there
  }
}
```

And use it in the reducer:

```
case "CONNECTOR_CONNECTION_FULFILLED":
   state = {
     ...state,
     appState: 'loggedIn',
   };
   state.ourPlayer = new Player(action.payload.player)

   break;
```